# Proxmox VM says disk is full but can't find the files taking up space

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtual-machine, virtualization, proxmox

I have a Proxmox VM running Ubuntu, which I use to self host some web apps and as a media server.

I've run into a problem whereby the disk has become full. The virtual disk assigned to the VM by Proxmox is 85GB in size.

When I run `df -h` I get the following output which clearly shows that `/` is 100% full.

[image: df -h]

However, when I run `ncdu` (with some mounted cifs shares excluded) to try and find the files that are taking the space I get the following output indicating that the total disk usage is only 30.3GB. What's with the discrepancy, and how can I find the missing 50GB of files?

[image: ncdu --exclude /mnt/zpool /]

I have run `lsof -nP +L1` to see if there's some pending file deletes but can't see anything out of the ordinary there:

[image: lsof -nP +L1]

I've tried rebooting but that doesn't seem to help.

Any help/advice appreciated.

Comment: Hit Win key, then type `disk usage` and click on the icon that appears. Select `/ ` and let the software churn on it... Find the `Treemap chart` icon in the lower border of the window and click on it... now browse the map for large files (large blobs are interesting, but may be folders, not files).

Comment: It's runing on a server so it doesn't have a desktop GUI. I would also guess that ```disk usage``` is using ```du``` in the backend so would have the same results.

Comment: "Disk usage Analyzer" <==> apt install baobab, it displays size of files and folders graphically.

Comment: Open a terminal/bash -> `find -type f -printf "%16s %p\n" | sort -n | less` will list files and their sizes, largest last - type a `>` to go to the end of the list, when `less`displays the list.

Comment: Host OS == Linux? Yes: Do you have a `sshd` running in that VM?  Try `ssh -Y ...` into the vm and launch `baobab` from the bash prompt in ssh.

Comment: compare `df -h /` with `du -hsx /` . If du is really lower than df, there's probably a deleted file kept by a process, or files kept invisible by a mountpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out my problem. I had mounted a CIF share to `/mnt/my_cif_share/` but before mounting this folder already had 50GB of files in it. As far as I can tell mounting over it essentially 'hides' those files from `du` and similar tools.

To rectify, you can either unmount the share, and delete the 'hidden' files. Or to fix this without unmounting, you can remount your root folder using `mount -o bind / /mnt` and you will be able to delete the files from there.

I found the answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/275206/disk-full-du-tells-different-how-to-further-investigate